# Are there any libraries that determine if a file is worth compressing before being transferred?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, compression, data-transfer

I've read that sometimes files like .mp3's or compressed images aren't worth compressing (with zlib for example) because they are already compressed and they'd waste more CPU resources than save space.  Are there any recommended libraries out there that can determine if a file is worth compressing before being transferred?

Comment: if a file can't be compressed it will end up only slightly larger than its original size in the worst case, also to figure out whether it is worth compressing will (naively) require a compression pass

Comment: @ratchetfreak To your first point, that's not really what I was asking.  Trying to compress an already compressed file wastes CPU cycles.  I'm trying to avoid doing so.  You mentioned a compression pass though, mind elaborating on that?  I assume you mean it needs to run through a pass to determine if it's worth compressing, so it's going to waste resources either way?

Comment: then the second part of my comment: assessing compressibility would (for the naive algos) require a compression pass and comparing the sizes, => endresult is that you still had to compress the file

Comment: @ratchetfreak So I assume then that, realistically, the only way to save any amount of resources would be to check the file extension and assume it's going to be a waste (or not) based on that alone...?

Comment: @Chris CPU cycles are NOTHING compared to the time it takes to read a file in from disk (i.e. you're comparing NANOSECONDS to MILLISECONDS, or a difference on the scale of 10^6 - millions of times slower).  It'd probably be just as fast to compress the file in-memory, and determine if the result is bigger than what's already on disk (without a fixed dictionary, even autocorrelation sometimes makes compression efficiency estimates very inaccurate).

Comment: @Breakthrough they're not being written to the disk locally, they're being transferred via network.  That's my primary reason for compressing them, to save time/bandwidth.  And when you're trying to compress several hundred files every second the cycles add up.

Comment: whoops, I misread your comment.. read/written.. they're sitting in memory to be passed along in any event.

Comment: @Chris well then yeah, compressing in memory is the way to do it.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, in most cases `file(1)` will tell you enough to know if compressing is worthwhile _without_ compressing (depending on the file contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression in general works by removing redundant constructs out of the data stream in a reversible manner.

One of the measures you can use to find how much of the date can be considered redundant is [autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) where the lower it is the less the signal will be compressible (exceptions do exist depending on the algorithm used).

However the lowest order algorithm to find the autocorrelation is of the order of `O(n*log(n))`. I believe that most compression algorithm are of the order `O(n)` making it a waste to run it on very long files. (it would be more efficient to just try to compress and check file sizes)

Comment: [Relevant SO post for anyone who's curious](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189765/big-o-complexities-of-algorithms-lzw-and-huffman), confirming what the OP said above.  Huffman and LZW encoding both run in `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

In StoreBackup, you can define rules. A rule can be a combination of different checks, eg. depending on the file suffix. But there also is a special function, COMPRESSION_CHECK, which decides depending on the contents of a file. It does not make much sense to check every file with COMPRESSION_CHECK, therefore you can define eg. the following:

1. all files ending .jpg and .mp3 are not compressed without any additional checks
2. all files ending .doc and .pdf are compressed in all cases without any additional checks
3. all files smaller than 1k are not compressed without any additional checks
4. all other files are checked with function COMPRESSION_CHECK

This is a behavior described in the referenced [document](http://www.nongnu.org/storebackup/en/node45.html).

(You could eg. also define rules that additionally never compresses files from a special person or group for easier restore with a file browser, but that's not related your questions)

Comment: Yeah I saw that, all that does it check the file extensions and size of file though.  I was hoping for something more elaborate.

Comment: Based on your reply to @ratchetfreak that's the best that can be done, right?

Comment: Apparently, I was more or less looking for other options, if any existed.  I'd upvote if I could, but I don't have any Rep on SuperUser yet.  (Really don't understand why Rep doesn't transfer between Stack sites.)

Comment: @Chris once you get over some barrier you get a 100 rep bonus on any new site you sign on on